# Recursive Permutation Generator, swapping list items not working

Tags: python, recursion, generator, permutation

I want to systematically generate permutations of the alphabet. 
I cannot don't want to use python itertools.permutation, because pregenerating a list of every permutation causes my computer to crash (first time i actually got it to force a shutdown, it was pretty great).

Therefore, my new approach is to generate and test each key on the fly. Currently, I am trying to handle this with recursion.

My idea is to start with the largest list (i'll use a 3 element list as an example), recurse in to smaller list until the list is two elements long. Then, it will print the list, swap the last two, print the list again, and return up one level and repeat.

For example, for 123

> 123 (swap position 0 with position 0)
>
> ```
>     23    --> 123 (swap position 1 with position 1)
>     32    --> 132 (swap position 1 with position 2)
> ```
>
> 213 (swap position 0 with position 1)
>
> ```
>     13    --> 213 (swap position 1 with position 1)
>     31    --> 231 (swap position 1 with position 2)
> ```
>
> 321 (swap position 0 with position 2)
>
> ```
>     21    --> 321 (swap position 1 with position 1)
>     12    --> 312 (swap position 1 with position 2)
> ```

for a four letter number (1234)

> 1234 (swap position 0 with position 0)
>
> ```
>     234    (swap position 1 with position 1)
>
>            34 --> 1234
>            43 --> 1243
>     324    (swap position 1 with position 2)
>            24 --> 1324
>            42 --> 1342
>     432    (swap position 1 with position 3)
>            32 --> 1432
>            23 --> 1423
> ```
>
> 2134 (swap position 0 for position 1)
>           134    (swap position 1 with position 1)
>                  34 --> 2134
>                  43 --> 2143
>           314    (swap position 1 with position 2)
>                  14--> 2314
>                  41--> 2341
>           431    (swap position 1 with position 3)
>                  31--> 2431
>                  13 -->2413

This is the code i currently have for the recursion, but its causing me a lot of grief, recursion not being my strong suit. Here's what i have.

```
def perm(x, y, key):
    print "Perm called: X=",x,", Y=",y,", key=",key
    while (x<y):

        print "\tLooping Inward"

        print "\t", x," ",y," ", key
        x=x+1
        key=perm(x, y, key)
        swap(x,y,key)
        print "\tAfter 'swap':",x," ",y," ", key, "\n"

    print "\nFull Depth Reached"
    #print key, " SWAPPED:? ",swap(x,y,key)
    print swap(x, y, key)
    print " X=",x,", Y=",y,", key=",key
    return key

def swap(x, y, key):
    v=key[x]
    key[x]=key[y]
    key[y]=v
    return key
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is a really cool project and I don't want to abandon it.

Thanks to all! Comments on my method or anything are welcome.

Comment: Firstly, itertools doesn't pregenerate the list unless you were doing it wrong. Secondly, is it broken or you just want better code? If you are looking for better code you just post the code for a review at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: i will revise and repost there, thank you

Comment: Seconding Winston Ewert; `itertools.permutations` does not pregenerate all the permutations, and as far as I can tell is exactly what you need. Perhaps you tried to do something like print all its results, or stick them in a list, which caused it to have to generate them all to satisfy the request?

Comment: only do that if it works. That site is for improving working code not fixing broken code. Its not clear to me from your post whether the code is broken. If it is, you need to specify on this site exactly how it differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened upon my old question later in my career

To efficiently do this, you want to write a **generator**.

Instead of returning a list of all of the permutations, which requires that you store them (all of them) in memory, **a generator returns one permutation** (one element of this list), then pauses, and then computes the next one when you ask for it.

The advantages to generators are:

- Take up much less space.

  - Generators take up between 40 and 80 bytes of space. One generators can have generate millions of items.
  - A list with one item takes up 40 bytes. A list with 1000 items takes up 4560 bytes
- More efficient

  - Only computes as many values as you need. In permuting the alphabet, if the correct permutation was found before the end of the list, the time spend generating all of the other permutations was wasted.

(Itertools.permutation is an example of a generator)

#### How do I Write a Generator?

Writing a generator in python is actually very easy. 

Basically, write code that would work for generating a list of permutations. Now, instead of writing `resultList+=[ resultItem ]`, write `yield(resultItem)`.

Now you've made a generator. If I wanted to loop over my generator, I could write

```
for i in myGenerator:
```

It's that easy.

Below is a generator for the code that I tried to write long ago:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a really good idea, but keeping track of the positions might get a bit difficult to deal with.  The general way I've seen for generating permutations recursively is a function which takes two string arguments: one to strip characters from (`str`) and one to add characters to (`soFar`).

When generating a permutation then we can think of taking characters from `str` and adding them to `soFar`.  Assume we have a function `perm` that takes these two arguments and finds all permutations of `str`.  We can then consider the current string `str`.  We'll have permutations beginning with each character in `str` so we just need to loop over `str`, using each of these characters as the initial character and calling perm on the characters remaining in the string:

```
// half python half pseudocode    
def perm(str, soFar):
    if(str == ""):
        print soFar // here we have a valid permutation
        return

    for i = 0 to str.length:
        next = soFar + str[i]
        remaining = str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i+1)
        perm(remaining, next)
```